# How to set unsigned integer in Android for byte[] length

Tags: java, android

This is 2 simple code for me to check how byte[] in android work

```
System.out.println("1 "+c.length+" "+PC1Bytes.length+" "+PC2Bytes.length+" "+RBytes.length+" "+VBytes.length +" "+packet.length);
System.out.println("1 "+(int)CByteslength+" "+(int)PC1Byteslength+" "+(int)PC2Byteslength+" "+(int)RByteslength+" "+(int)VByteslength +" "+packet.length);
```

My result is
`System.out: 1 16 97 97 49 128 136`
`System.out: 1 16 97 97 49 -128 136`
 ok how could i set to real length of this packet?
Netbeans works fine,but android didn't

Comment: Do you have a easy way to get rea length byte[]? because it workded fine Neabeans but Android Studio didn't.
I don't know why?. still same JDK

Comment: If `VBytes` is a `byte[]`, you get its length exactly as you've written it: `VBytes.length`.  Are you asking why `VBytes.length` is different from `(int) VByteslength`?  If so, you'll need to show what `VByteslength` is and how you set its value.

Comment: `byte[] VBytes = v.toByteArray();
        byte VByteslength = (byte)VBytes.length;` i want to ask why Netbeans diffrent Android. because i used same code

Comment: @QuangVu If you get a result of 128 in Netbeans, then Netbeans is broken! You should get -128. (That is, this code should always give -128, even though that's not what you actually wanted)

Comment: @immibis Could Netbeans be silently fixing the incorrect use of a `byte` to hold an array length?  I doubt it, but then again, Netbeans is weird.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede If Netbeans is fixing it behind your back, then that's still broken - what if you *wanted* -128 for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `byte` is signed and cannot hold the value `128`.  Change it to

```
int VByteslength = VBytes.length;
```

Or better yet, just use `VBytes.length`.